# Visual Studio 2022 MAUI - Button pressed and released effect

Tags: android, maui

I am trying to create simple buttons with different appearance depending on the state, a classic windows form button, but I cannot find the easy way to do that in MAUI.

So far I did the following:

- define the button in the xaml with a default color

`<Button Text="POSITIVE" x:Name="positive" IsEnabled="True" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" BackgroundColor="DarkGray"/>`

- I create a variable to keep track of the status of the button

> private bool isPositivePressed = false;

- in the main function, I define the handler for the click action

  ```
  positive.Clicked += (sender, args) =>
  {
      isPositivePressed = !isPositivePressed;
      UpdateButtonVisualState(positive, isPositivePressed);
  };
  ```
- finally the function will change the color of the button depending on the state of the button which is passed by parameter.

`private void UpdateButtonVisualState(Button button, bool state)
{
button.BackgroundColor = state ? Color.FromRgb(81, 43, 212) : Colors.DarkGray;

}`

This code works in the Android emulator, but it does not work in a real android phone.

Could someone point to me a better and consistent way to achieve the same behavior?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [press and release method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/button#press-and-release-the-button) for the button.

Here is the code you can refer to in the .xaml:

```
<Button Text="Press to Rotate Text!"
                VerticalOptions="Center"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                Pressed="Button_Pressed"
                Released="Button_Released" />
```

Here is the code in the code behind.

```
private void Button_Pressed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            Button button = (Button)sender;
            button.BackgroundColor = Colors.AliceBlue;
    }

    private void Button_Released(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            Button btn = (Button)sender;
            btn.BackgroundColor = Colors.BlueViolet;
    }
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the help but following the @dpmaddy's advice I will try to implement it with the styles (visual states). thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, are you looking to do this based on the state of some ViewModel or is it more around whether it is currently pressed? If the latter, hopefully the answer below helps :)

One way you could achieve this would be to use the `VisualStateManager` style (See [visual states](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/visual-states) in .NET Maui documentations). I understand visual states as a means to "make visual changes to the UI from code", allowing you to fully customize the Maui components.

If your looking to do this programmatically (i.e., in C# code behind), checkout  the [define custom visual states](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/visual-states#define-custom-visual-states) documentation.

As an example, below I've defined visual states in a `ContentPage.Resources`, but you could achieve the same logic, inline per-button, or via `Styles.xaml`. In this example, I simply update the buttons `BackgroundColor` when our button is "[pressed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/button#button-visual-states)".

```xml
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor"
                Value="White" />

        <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
            <VisualStateGroupList>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled" />
                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                        <!-- define your custom 'pressed' styles here -->
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor"
                                    Value="Orange" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateGroupList>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

Comment: hi @dpmaddy, I followed your advice but I didnt manage to make it work. I explain on details in my own answer, here I could not paste code :/

Comment: Hey @YaKs, I can't seem to see the updates in your answer above. Did you manage to have a read of the documentation I linked above?